# An app with a variable of type [String:[String: [[Double]]]] containing 5000 entries won't compile. Should it be stored in a separate file?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I am new to Swift and iOS development. I currently have the following data structure `[String:[String: [[Double]]]]` in an app. Keys Y and Z both have around 2500 arrays.

```
"X": [
       "Y": [ [1,1,1], 
              (....),
              [2500, 2500, 2500] 
             ],

       "Z": [ [1,1,1], 
              (....),
              [2500, 2500, 2500] 
             ]
      ]
```

The program doesn't even compile. Without this construction, it works fine. What should I do here ? Shall I write this data to a file and have Swift read data from this file ? I'm not really sure what is the best way to approach this problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add more information including the compilation error and source code for the line(s) it fails at.

Comment: Never hardcode so much data directly in code.

Comment: It is a "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11". No lines involved, just a general failure. It is clear to me that it is because of the hard coding. My question is, what should I do to achieve what I want ? i.e. to read numbers from this structure and mathematically manipulate them...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store this data in app (without downloading from network), you would save it in `JSON` or `plist` format and parse when you want. You can use any framework for mapping like [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) or do it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I need the numbers in the array to calculate tax returns. For this prototype and for learning reasons I am storing everything in the app, so no downloading. Could you please explain a bit further ?